# How to set collectionview cell to start at index '1' not '0' - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have two custom cell classes `HomeCell` & `CreateCell`. Ideally, the first cell should be the `CreateCell` & the `HomeCell's` should start at the index of '1' (After the first create cell) but currently, the `CreateCell` and the first `HomeCell` are overlapping. Is there a way I can set the `HomeCell's` to start at the index of '1'?

If there is any more code that needs to be provided, let me know.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CreateCell", for: indexPath) as! CreateCell
        //configure your cell here...
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCell
        cell.list = lists[indexPath.item]
        //configure your cell with list
        return cell
    }
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return lists.count
}
```

Comment: The code is fine. I hope the problem is somewhere in your UICollectionViewLayout if you use it.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the CreateCell and the first HomeCell are overlapping."_ Add a screenshot of the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to access  0th element of List on 1st index, you would need to change the code a little bit in your `cellForItemAt indexPath:`

```
cell.list = lists[indexPath.item - 1]
```

in this way, you will start the `HomeCell` views from 1st index

Also You would need to change the count of total items, as there is additional create cell.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return lists.count+1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexPath.item` in place of `indexPath.row`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CreateCell", for: indexPath) as! CreateCell
        //configure your cell here...
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCell
        cell.list = lists[indexPath.item]
        //configure your cell with list
        return cell
    }
}
```